# Segue URL between two UIWebViews in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, segue

I'd like to start by saying I'm very new to iOS application development. I am currently developing a native app for my church, United Church, that renders a special app-only fork of a WordPress website. I am writing in Swift and have the basic app built. The app has four tabs, and in the main "Home" tab I have two web views. One for the top slider, the other for the scrollable content below.

[image]

When the user taps anything in these web views that is linked to a URL, instead of loading the URL inside of the home tab, I'd like to pass the URL and segue into another view controller with a web view and a back button. Like the URL opened up a new view just to display the page, and when the user is done, taps the arrow back to the Home tab. Any help on how to get started with this is much appreciated. I've been researching for days but I haven't found anything for swift that helped me.

Comment: hybrid app in swift ?

Comment: @Varun Naharia Yes, sorry, a native app that is mostly web views. The pages displayed have been made specifically for the mobile apps for android and iOS though.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible. Think your webview as an entity by itself. I think it has no way to communicante event to swift on tapping particular area.

You could add your own UIButton on top of the webview but that's dirty imo, and it may be not possible because of your scrolling.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31708014/1585121) may help you

Answer (score 0):

implement WebView delegate in :

```
 func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if let url = webView.URL!{
        // create your other view and push it with the navigationController
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Cancel)
    }

}
```

in that function you can decide wether or not commit the navigation.
You create your second ViewControler (pass the url) and you cancel the navigation in the first viewController